# Sending data from UI5 to ABAP without gateway?

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap

I have been creating a basic OpenUI5 application, and aiming to implement SAP Gateway very soon.

I currently have a screen that populates an array with simple text-fields and a button. My aim is to send this array/table to a backend ABAP function module or class method. Can this be done? The table has the potential to be quite large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any problem as long as you do not try to send gigabytes or hundreds of megabytes over the network.

Sending the data to a class method will not be possible as the ABAP methods of classes are not RFC enabled. For this purpose you can use only function modules.

Comment: Thanks! I am happy to use function modules, but any ideas if it would be possible to use ABAP instance methods as opposed to class methods?

Comment: @user2271046 You could write instance methods, then inside the function group, create your object and then delegate the function module call to the chosen instance method.

Comment: The communication SAPUI5 -> SAP usually doesn't work with custom RFCs but via HTTP (i.e. the ABAP RFC HTTP_DISPATCH_REQUEST internally calls an HTTP request handler class that is configured to serve requests on a certain path via transaction `SICF` Therefore, it's not necessary to write a function module. A method of an HTTP handler suffices.

Comment: I have installed this in our SAP system and getting information from the ABAP GET_ENTITYSET method is a breeze, but I haven't tried sending back yet, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a write capable oData service that accepts oData post requests from an UI5 application and writes data to a database table. During implementation of this oData service you may call any ABAP backend class methods of objects that you need to instantiate.

The most important point to realize is that the UI5 application is stateless. The application and all classes are instantiated for processing of the single request and die immediately after the request is processed.

Comment: Initially I was going to build a table row by row but I think i'll send the entire table now, thanks for the help!